# How to fix gwt eclipse plugin after java change?

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt

I changed java from 6 to 7. Now when I'm starting eclipse I get

`jre version 1.6.0 version 1.7.0 or later is needed to run google plugin for eclipse.`

And gwt plugin doesn't work but everything else works fine. How could I fix it? I read about the same issue on mac and eclipse indigo but I have a common pc with eclipse kepler.

Comment: Windows > Preferences > Java > Installed JREs. Add and check the jre7 folder

Comment: Project > Properties> Google > Web Toolkit. Remove previous installed GWT SDK and add it again.

Comment: Which version of GWT are you using?

Comment: GWT version 2.5.1. Should I update it too?

Comment: @cadmy Java 7 is [only supported from GWT 2.6.0 up](http://www.gwtproject.org/release-notes.html#Release_Notes_2_6_0).

Comment: I changed gwt but it doesn't work